# C# - Call/write a deserialization method in another class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to de-serialize a class in order to save user specific values (like a dirpath) in an XML-file.

Here's a snippet of my class:

```
      [Serializable]
       public class CustomSettings
        {
            public string initPath;
            public string InitPath => initPath;
        }
```

Both the serialization and deserialization work perfectly fine if I do this inside my `MainWindow` class:

```
            CustomSettings cs = new CustomSettings();
            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
            StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml");
            mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, cs);
            myWriter.Close();
```

And for the deserialization:

```
        CustomSettings cs = new CustomSettings();
        XmlSerializer _mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
        FileStream myFstream = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open);
        cs = (CustomSettings)_mySerializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
        myFstream.Close();
```

Now since I need to do the de-serialization a few times, I figured I write two methods which will do the above work, but due to readability I want them to be inside another class.

In `MainWindow` I call this method inside another class, which again, works as intended:

```
 public void WriteSettingsToFile(CustomSettings cs)
    {
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
        StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml");
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, cs);
        myWriter.Close();
    }
```

The de-serialization function I wrote does not work, though. It loads the file successfully, returning the correct path value but as soon as it returns to the calling class, the string is always null. I rewrote the method several times, trying void, non-void returning a string, static etc. but I'm stuck.

Any help and ideas are appreciated!

**Edit:**
Here's one of the tries with the deserialization method:

```
 public void GetInitPath(CustomSettings cs)
    {
        XmlSerializer _mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
        FileStream myFstream = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open);
        cs = (CustomSettings)_mySerializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
        myFstream.Close();

    }
```

**Edit 2:**

With the help of Matthew Watson I was able to solve my problem.

```
 public void GetInitPath(ref CustomSettings cs)
    {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));

        using (var myFstream = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            cs = (CustomSettings)serializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually included the code for the deserialisation that doesn't work...

Comment: It looks exactly the same as provided in my post...

Comment: You instance of the class is cs : CustomSettings cs = new CustomSettings();  So you need to set "cs" to a parent class to a parent object like List<CustomSettings> settings = new List<CustomSettings>();   settings.Add(cs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your method that doesn't work:

```
public void GetInitPath(CustomSettings cs)
{
    XmlSerializer _mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
    FileStream    myFstream     = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open);
    cs                          = (CustomSettings)_mySerializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
    myFstream.Close();
}
```

The problem with this method is that it DOESN'T RETURN THE RESULT.

It overwrites the reference to `cs` that is passed to `GetInitPath()` with a reference to the object returned from `.Deserialise()`, but that does NOT change the original object passed to `GetInitPath()`.

The solution is either to declare the parameter as a `ref` parameter, or (much better) change the method to return the result like so:

```
public CustomSettings GetInitPath()
{
    XmlSerializer _mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));
    FileStream    myFstream     = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open);
    var cs                      = (CustomSettings)_mySerializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
    myFstream.Close();

    return cs;
}
```

Another observation: It's better to use `using` when possible to wrap resources that are disposable. If you do that, your method would look like this:

```
public CustomSettings GetInitPath()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSettings));

    using (var myFstream = new FileStream(@"U:\Alex\prefs.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        return (CustomSettings) serializer.Deserialize(myFstream);
    }
}
```

This will close `myFstream` even if an exception occurs in `Deserialize()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately, returning the result back to the caller causes the strings to be null, again. Both of my methods are now inside a `TestMethods` class. In `MainWindow` I call the de-serialization method like this: `tm.GetInitPath()`. Then, I want to pass the `InitPath`-string to a local string `initialPath` but it's null. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So apparently, as you mentioned, the `ref`-keyword did the trick. All values are now passed correctly to the calling function. I will update my OP with the working solution. Thank you for your help! 
Could you please explain why it would be better to use a return-value instead of the `ref`? I honestly never used `ref` in my methods, since non-void-methods usually worked for me, except for this case.

Comment: It's better to use a return because the method is creating an entirely new object, so it's incorrect to make code create a dummy object just to have it replaced by a real one.